# Como implementar Galeria de foto do PrimeNG?

Tags: angular

Saudação pessoal,

Estou tentando implementa uma galeria de imagens como você podem ver no modelo demonstrativo do PrimeNG logo abaixo;

[Galeria](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/galleria)

Porém estou tendo dificuldade devido a falta de experiência, por favor, o meu objetivo e implementar esta biblioteca.

Essas são as informações estão no meu banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu carrego a página ela já consegue carregar a lista de objetos como podem ver na figura abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é classe do componente;

```
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { EventoService } from './../../core/evento.service';
import { Evento } from './../../models/evento';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-evento',
  templateUrl: './evento.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./evento.component.css']
})
export class EventoComponent implements OnInit {

  public title: string;
  public eventos: Evento[];
  public url;

  constructor(
    private _eventoService: EventoService,
  ) {
      this.title = 'Fotos de Eventos';
      this.url = environment.url;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEventos();
  }


  getEventos() {
    this._eventoService.getEventos().subscribe(
      response => {
        if (!response.eventos) {

        } else {
          this.eventos = response.eventos;
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }


}
```

**O problema e não tem muitas informações na documentação.**

ESSA FOI MINHA TENTATIVA;

Meu HTML;

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>

       <form >
          <p-galleria [images]="eventos" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" [showCaption]="true"></p-galleria>
      </form>


</div>
```

Em tela ficou assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os slides estão passando em branco, sem aparecer imagens, o problema é não estou conseguindo montar a lógica.

Essa é minha interface.

```
export class Evento {
    constructor (
        public _id: string,
        public name: string,
        public description: string,
        public year: number,
        public image: string,
        public user: string
     ) {}
}
```

Se eu montar assim aparece as imagens, **porém não fica como na implementação da biblioteca do PrimeNG**;

```
<div class="col-lg-12" [@fadeIn]>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>

  <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="animal-image-mask">
        <img src="{{ url + 'get-image-evento/' + evento.image }}" alt="{{evento.name}}" *ngIf="evento.image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/270x200" alt="{{evento.name}}" *ngIf="!evento.image">
       </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Eu fiz conforme a sugestão;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu colocquei assim;

```
getEventos() {
    this._eventoService.getEventos().subscribe(
      response => {
        if (!response.eventos) {

        } else {
          this.eventos = response.eventos.map(evento => {
            return {
              source: evento.image,
              alt: evento.description,
              title: evento.name
             }
           });
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: tem como voce postar seu html e como e essa sua interface evento?

Comment: @EduardoVargas acabei de atualizar minha postagem poderia por favor dá uma olhada para conseguir me ajudar.

Comment: fiz mais uma outra atualização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta mapear pra interface que ele usa na documentação.

```
else {
      this.eventos = response.eventos.map(evento=>{
       return {
         source:  this.url + 'get-image-evento/' + evento.image ,
         alt: evento.description,
         title: evento.name
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: A interface já estava mapeada, porém apresenta o mesmo erro de antes.

Comment: Me desculpe, pegou a maioria das coisas, porém a imagem não apareceu

Comment: eu atualizei a postagem, poderia dá uma olhada está faltando pouco.

Comment: eu vi no seu html que evento.image não é  a url completa eu tentei editar ali mas é so colocar uma url que faca sentido.

Comment: opa desculpe acabei de ver agora, vou testar

Comment: hahahaha deu certo muito obrigado mesmo. :)

Comment: Eu iria precisar só de mais uma ajuda, mas se não for possível eu vou compreender, minhas imagens estão de 4608 x 3072 é uma resolução muito alta, eu poderia pegar as minhas  500 imagens e redimensionar-las  uma por uma no Photoshop, mas iria ser uma retrabalho muito grande, será que nessa implementação tem alguma configuração para redimensionar as imagens automaticamente ?

Comment: Eu usaria algum site pra calcular a proporção da imagem tipo https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/ e setaria o width a e height do componente pra algo que fique bacana nessa proporção.